# sql counting references in other table

Tags: sql

If a book as 0 sales, it gets not listed by this query.

But I really need it there :)

How can this be fixed ?

```
SELECT 
    description, author, count(sales.*) as "amount of sales"
FROM 
    books, sales 
WHERE 
    books.id = sales.book_id 
GROUP BY 
    books.id;
```

Comment: give some sample data

Comment: its abstracted, but just assume these two tables with some entries.. including books with no sales entries

books
id | description | author
1  | harry potter | matthew
2  | tributes        | francis

sales 
id | book_id | ...
1  | 1           | ..
2  | 1           | ..

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Here's a handy guide to posting [good examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You're more likely to get an answer if you follow these tips.

Comment: You need an [OUTER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).  This allows you to include all data from one table, with any matching data from another.  Your current query acts like an INNER JOIN (although you are using an older syntax style, which I suggest moving away from).  This means you are only seeing rows that appear in all the tables.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Qaualify column names, so we know which tables the columns belong to! (E.g. books.columnx instead of just columnx.)

Answer (score 5):

You need an outer join:

```
SELECT description, 
       author, 
       count(sales.book_id) as "amount of sales"
FROM books
  LEFT JOIN sales ON books.id = sales.book_id 
GROUP BY books.id;
```

The outer join will return all books. For books that have no sales, all columns from the `sales` table will be null. As aggregate functions ignore null values, `count(sales.book_id)` will return zero for those books that have not been sold.

This is also a nice example why the old, outdated implicit join in the `where` clause shouldn't be used any longer: you can't write an outer join using that syntax.

Comment: Of course you can write Outer Joins, using some more old, outdated, deprecated syntax like `=*` or `(+)` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: just don't even start talking about those clunky, old, deprecated possibilities...

Comment: @dnoeth: not with standard SQL and this question is only tagged `sql`, no specific product given.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left join`:

```
SELECT b.description, b.author, count(s.book_id) as NumSales
FROM books b left join
     sales s
     ON b.id = s.book_id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

In general, you should always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Also, table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.